# Error serializing model in webserver

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, ef-code-first

Im having troubles with an application. I have a MVC application that query a database (and some webservices) and return me information in JSON. In My Local Machine works like a charm but when I upload it to the webserver I get this error:

"Error getting value from '_owner' on 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelationshipManager'."
(You can see the whole error page in http://canedroid.com/mvc/api/requests/getlastcheckins)

I tried disabling proxies and lazy loading with:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        base.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }
```

And nothing happens.

Model:

```
namespace CaneDroid.MVCApp.Models
{
public class CaneDroidContext : DbContext,ICaneDroidDataSource
{
    public CaneDroidContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        base.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

    public DbSet<Checkin> mdlCheckins { get; set; }
    public DbSet<configAndroid> configAndroid { get; set; }


    IQueryable<Checkin> ICaneDroidDataSource.Checkins
    {
        get { return mdlCheckins; }
    }
}

public class Checkin
{

    public Checkin()
    {
        visto = false;
    }

    [Key,DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual string fsqCheckinId { get; set; }
    public virtual string text { get; set; }
    public virtual string usrId { get; set; }
    public virtual string usrFrstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string usrLstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string venueId { get; set; }
    public virtual string venueName { get; set; }
    public virtual string venueAddress { get; set; }
    public virtual string venueCrossStreet { get; set; }
    public virtual string venueLat { get; set; }
    public virtual string venueLng { get; set; }
    public virtual string venueCity { get; set; }
    public virtual bool visto { get; set; }
}

public class configAndroid
{
    [Key, DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public bool value { get; set; }
}
```

}

Action in controller:

```
public R getLastCheckins()
    {
        var responseJson = R.getLastCheckins(db);
        return responseJson;
    }

public static R getLastCheckins(CaneDroidContext db)
    {
        var cache = db.mdlCheckins.OrderByDescending(q => q.Id).Take(10);
        return new R(cache, null, null, null, null, null);
    }
```

I don't know what else can I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. I found the solution. The problem was the Context variable.

```
private static CaneDroidContext db = new CaneDroidContext();
```

When I modified it and made it static everything started to work normally.